# Why do I get strange output from Perl using SQL?

Tags: perl, unix

Here is my Perl code:

```
foreach my $line  (@tmp_field_validation)
{
        chomp $line;
        my ($cycle_code,$cycle_month,$cycle_year)= split /\s*\|\s*/, $line;
        $cycle_code=~ s/^\s*(.*)\s*$/$1/;
        $cycle_month=~ s/^\s*(.*)\s*$/$1/;
        $cycle_year=~ s/^\s*(.*)\s*$/$1/;
        print "$line\n";
        print "$cycle_code|$cycle_month|$cycle_year";
}
```

Here is the output:

```
         1          10       2009
1           10       2009||
```

What's wrong over here?
I expected the pipes to be between the variables.  Why are the pipes getting printed after all the three variables?

***EDIT:*** tmp_field_validation is the output of an sql query which has a select statement like :

```
select cycle_code,cycle_month,cycle_year from ....
```

so the output is coming as 3 different columns  when i executed the query in TOAD. but the same query when used in this script how could it be possible that the output is considered as the single field cycle_code

Answer (score 4):

You should add the following line to the top of your code:

```
use warnings;
```

Or, if your already have it there, you should pay attention to the warning messages you receive.  Others have correctly pointed out that your input line does not have any literal pipes.  I think you really want something like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @tmp_field_validation = ("         1          10       2009\n");

foreach my $line  (@tmp_field_validation)
{
        chomp $line;
        $line =~ s/^\s*//;
        my ($cycle_code,$cycle_month,$cycle_year)= split /\s+/, $line;
        print "$line\n";
        print "$cycle_code|$cycle_month|$cycle_year";
}
```

Outputs the following:

```
1          10       2009
1|10|2009
```

Answer (score 3):

Because the entire line got stocked in the $cycle_code variable. The other two variables are empty strings.

Comment: This is actually an entirely correct answer, but it would be helpful to mention that the *reason* it happens is because the split is on vertical vertical bars (surrounded by optional whitespace), and there are no vertical bars in the input.